# how to exchange it with jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="price">
    <a href="http://example.com/<?php echo $_GET['Path'];?>&sort=3a">Price Up</a> 
    <a href="http://example.com/<?php echo $_GET['Path'];?>&sort=3d">Price Down</a>
</div>
<div id="name">
    <a href="http://example.com/<?php echo $_GET['Path'];?>&sort=2a">Name Up </a> 
    <a href="http://example.com/<?php echo $_GET['Path'];?>&sort=2d">Name Down </a>
</div>
```

When the user clicks **Price Up**, the **Price Down** should show and **Price Up** should be hidden and vice versa. Similarly for **Name Up** and **Name Down**.

Why this can't work?

```
$("#price a,#name a").eq(1).hide();
```

Comment: Why don't you use classes to make your code more readable and avoid that kind of problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off all, this doesn't work:

```
$("#price a,#name a").eq(1).hide();
```

because `'#price a, #name a'` matches four elements then [`eq(1)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) selects the second of the four (`eq` uses zero based indexes) so only **Price Down** gets hidden. If you want to hide both **Down** links then you want the [`:eq` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/):

```
$('#price a:eq(1), #name a:eq(1)').hide();
```

To toggle them you just need just a simple [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) handler on all the `<a>` elements:

```
$('#price a, #name a').click(function() {
    $(this).hide().siblings().show();
    return false;
});
```

The [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) call is an easy way to get all elements at the same level as `this` without include `this` in the list. You'd need to alter that slightly if your `<div>`s contained something other than the `<a>` elements that you're interested in.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/xwB2b/

---

**Update For Comments**: If you need to keep the links as links but also include some sort of show/hide toggling then you'll need another control (or your users will hate you for trying to make one control do two things). Something like this:

```
<div id="price">
    <button class="flipper">Flip</button>
    <a href="http://example.com/<?php echo $_GET['Path'];?>&sort=3a">Price Up</a> 
    <a href="http://example.com/<?php echo $_GET['Path'];?>&sort=3d">Price Down</a>
</div>
<div id="name">
    <button class="flipper">Flip</button>
    <a href="http://example.com/<?php echo $_GET['Path'];?>&sort=2a">Name Up </a> 
    <a href="http://example.com/<?php echo $_GET['Path'];?>&sort=2d">Name Down </a>
</div>
```

And this:

```
$('#price a:eq(1), #name a:eq(1)').hide();
$('.flipper').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().toggle();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/CAAan/

You could style the `<button>` any way you wanted.

Comment: oh,damn it. this problem can't use click event, if using the click, i can't click the link. is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: @dreamchaser: How do you intend to toggle them? Clicking those links will replace the whole page so you don't need any jQuery at all; if you have some AJAX stuff for the sorting then you can just add another click handler for that: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/xwB2b/1/

Comment: how to write another click handler. when click the price up text, invoke this page http://example.com/<?php echo $_GET['Path'];?>&sort=3a. the rest are the same thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `.toggle()` instead.

```
$("#price a").toggle(); $("#name a").toggle();
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: this is my code but it doesn't work. when i click the text $("#price a",#name a").eq(1).hide();
$("#price a").toggle(); $("#name a").toggle();

Answer (score 0):

there is a typo that the href value of "Price Down"..

`$("#price a,#name a")` returns the four of the links, so eq(1) will get the "Price Down" link to hide.

so for price and name, you need to write the script seperately.